# timeInterval with nested timeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

after page loading I need:

- wait 7 sec
- `aniwrap.text()` - `LOREM IPSUM`
- wait 7 sec
- `aniwrap.text()` - `DOLOR SIT`
- and so on - repeating the pause and changing the text

In my try - I have only the second text, without the first one

any help?

```js
var i;
var txt = '';
var arra = ["LOREM IPSUM", "DOLOR SIT"];
var aniwrap = $('#aniwrap');

function write() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("aniwrap").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(write, 70);
  }
}

function single(){
    $(arra).each(function(el, val){
        setTimeout(function(){
            aniwrap.text('');
            i = 0;
            console.log(val);
            txt = val;
            write();
        }, 7000);
    });
}

$(window).on('load', function(){
    setInterval(single, 7000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='aniwrap'></div>
```

Comment: Did you mean to timeout with `70` instead of `7000` ?

Comment: @AndyRay - pause between letter typing is 70 and between sentence typing is 7000

Comment: do you want to create a list ?

Comment: @sonEtLumiere - I need the above funcionality - anyway

Comment: `$(array).each` — you will want this to be `$.each(array)`. `$(selector).each(fn)` is for elements, `$.each(array, fn)` is for arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable that determines the index of the word in the **arra** array:

```
var index = 0;
```

I removed the `each()` method and did it in a different way:

```
function single(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    index++;
      ...
      txt = arra[index % arra.length];
      ...
  }, 7000);
}
```

```js
var i;
var index = 0;
var txt = '';
var arra = ["LOREM IPSUM", "DOLOR SIT"];
var aniwrap = $('#aniwrap');

function write() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("aniwrap").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(write, 70);
  }
}

function single(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    index++;
      aniwrap.text('');
      i = 0;
      console.log(arra[index % arra.length]);
      txt = arra[index % arra.length];
      write();
  }, 7000);
}

$(window).on('load', function(){
    setInterval(single, 7000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='aniwrap'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple problems: `$(element/selector).each(cb)` is for jQuery objects, what you want for iteration over an array is `$.each(array, cb)` (or just `array.forEach`. The other problem is that you're creating the `setTimeout`s in the loop, at the same time). Unless I'm missing something you don't actually need the loop or setTimeout in `single` at all.

```
var idx = 0;
function single() {
  if (idx == arra.length) {
    idx = 0;
  }
  var val = arra[idx];
  aniwrap.text('');
  idx++;
  i = 0;
  txt = val;
  write();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `single` sets up two timer callbacks that will execute successively but more or less immediately one after the other (they are both use a 7000ms timer).

On the first timer callback `i` is set to `0` and `txt` to `LOREM IPSUM`, and `write` will output the first letter `L`.

Before a page refresh has a chance to occur (in most cases), the second timer call back executes, which clears the text content of `#aniwrap`, resets the character pointer `i` back to zero and replaces the text with `DOLOR SIT`.

Now `write` will continue to output `DOLOR SIT` one letter at a time, but because the timer created in the first call to `write` was never cancelled, at twice the letter rate anticipated.

This is a timing problem. One way of resolving it would be to set up a different time delay for each line in `arra`, with another choice being to use a single 7000ms timer to write a single line and then call itself back for the next line with a timer.

Here's an example of the first option with minimum modification of the posted code:

```js
"use strict";
var i;
var txt = '';
var arra = ["LOREM IPSUM", "DOLOR SIT"];
var aniwrap = $('#aniwrap');

function write() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("aniwrap").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(write, 70);
  }
}

function single(){
    $(arra).each(function(index, val){  // argument name change
        setTimeout(function(){
            aniwrap.text('');
            i = 0;
            console.log(val);
            txt = val;
            write();
        }, 3500 * index);  // <-- change
    });
}

$(window).on('load', function(){
    setInterval(single, 7000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='aniwrap'></div>
```

A third way of resolving the issue might be to put a fixed length pause between lines so they could be any length (timings reduced for this example):

```js
"use strict";
var i;
let lineNum = -1;
var txt = '';
var arra = ["LOREM IPSUM", "DOLOR SIT", "GAUDEAMUS IGITUR"];
var aniwrap = $('#aniwrap');

function write() {
  console.log(txt);
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("aniwrap").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(write, 70);
  }
  else setTimeout( nextLine, 3500);
}

function nextLine(){
    lineNum = ++ lineNum % arra.length;
    txt = arra[ lineNum];
    aniwrap.text('');
    i = 0;
    write();
}
 
$(window).on('load', nextLine)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='aniwrap'></div>
```

Comment: But in your case, the spacing between the words of the array is 3.5 seconds. For OP, an interval of 7 seconds is required between the occurrence of words.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov but for the purposes of illustration it's quicker to see the result.